# How effective is the Optical Chaff shoulder unit in AC5?

Tags: armored-core-5

The unit with the highest rating has an optical chaff effect rating of 35. There isn't any description as to what this does specifically besides that it affects lock on capability.

How does the other AC feel this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use Chaff in 1v1/Recon play as it's much easier to prevent yourself
>   from being targeted that attempting to hit your target in a 1v1 or
>   exposing your position during Recon. - http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/984945-armored-core-v/faqs/64037
>
> Optical Chaff confuses and redirects missiles as well as hide your IFF IDENT from the enemy operator. - http://forum.acgarage.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=14894&start=880#p228030
>
> Note that there is no Dual-Shoulder bonus for Optical Chaff. ME and a couple other  people from Core Nexus had screwed around with it for a while. Also, if there exists an enemy player on the opposing side with a Subcomputer, the effects of the Optical Chaff are completely negated prior to calculating the Subcomputer's effects. - http://forum.acgarage.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=17332&p=231854&hilit=optical+chaff#p231825
>
> Good ol' optical chaff should buy you some more time to dart between cover as you close the distance. As for weapons, go for accurate ones such as the Karasawa or Lotus, maximizing your chances of hitting him even if he's barely at the edge of your lock on range - http://forum.acgarage.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=17286&p=231153&hilit=optical+chaff#p231153

I don't believe the second through the last to be necessarily only talking about AC5, though it is unclear.